# Adding Rows Dynamically in a Table

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here I am trying to display the modal popup window with one text area and two dropdowns in a row. And I am trying to add row by clicking "AddNewRow" button in same popup window. For this I have written Javascript function.

```
    Java Script function for Adding row.   
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

          function addRow() {
              var tbody = document.getElementById(modaltable).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
              // create row
              var row = document.createElement("TR");
              // create table cell 1
              var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
              var strHtml1 = "<FONT SIZE=\"+3\"></FONT>";
              td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g, count);

              var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
              var strHtml2 = "<SELECT NAME=\"Alpha-Numeric Scramble\"><OPTION VALUE=\"Alpha-Numeric Scramble\">Alpha-Numeric Scramble<OPTION VALUE=\"Packed-Decimal Scramble\">Packed-Decimal Scramble<OPTION VALUE=\"Date-Time Scrambler\">Date-Time Scrambler</SELECT>";
              td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g, count);

              var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
              var strHtml3 = "<SELECT NAME=\"Yes\"><OPTION VALUE=\"Yes\">Yes<OPTION VALUE=\"No\">No</SELECT>";
              td2.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);

              row.appendChild(td1);
              row.appendChild(td2);
              row.appendChild(td3);

              count = parseInt(count) + 1;
              // append row to table
              tbody.appendChild(row);

          }
              </script>
```

This is For modal popup design.

```
    <table class="table .table-responsive" id ="modaltable">
    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td ><textarea class="form-control" id="comment" ></textarea></td>
            <td ><div class="dropdown">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Alpha-Numeric Scramble"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Packed-Decimal Scramble"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Date-Time Scrambler"/>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
             </div></td>
            <td><div class="dropdown">
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No"/>
             </asp:DropDownList>

             </div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

These are buttons in modal popup,

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="Addnewrow" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Add New Row" OnClientclick= "addRow()"/>
```

Here If I click "AddNewRow" button one row should add.

Unfortunately not able to displaying. What's the error in the above Java script. Any help Please.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: OnClientclick= "addRow()" this function is not triggering

Comment: what is happening when clicking on button?

Comment: Nothing happening sir. Just closing the popup window.

Comment: Because it is postbacking to server..

Comment: Ok. Then What Should I do.

Comment: I think you should use row=tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);

And then set the content of the row.

Comment: I tried with this option. Its not working sir.

Comment: Check the debugger of your browser and see if there is an error in the javascript console. That will help you identify the problem. I noticed you do `var tbody = document.getElementById(modaltable)...` when you actually should `var tbody = document.getElementById("modaltable")...`

Comment: var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
      var strHtml1 = "<FONT SIZE=\"+3\"></FONT>";
      td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g, count);                                              Getting error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happening in your code. You have used `<ASP:Button>` control for triggering your javascript function. It is better to use HTML `<button>` like below:

```
<button ID="Addnewrow" class="btn btn-primary" onclick= "addRow()"> Add New Row </button>
```

**OR**

If you want to use server side control then you should stop postback triggered after `OnClientClick`
Some changes needed in your code. 
First add `return false;` in your `function addRow() {` 
Then use `OnClientclick= "return addRow()"`

Comment: Sir after changing also same thing happening.

Comment: var td1 = document.createElement("TD"); var strHtml1 = "<FONT SIZE=\"+3\"></FONT>"; td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g, count); Getting error here . In place of "TD" what should I use.

Comment: what is count here? what do you want to write in `<td>`?

Comment: It should be `var strHtml1 = "<font size=\"3\"></font>";` and `var strHtml2 = "<select name=\"Alpha-Numeric_Scramble\"><option value=\"Alpha-Numeric Scramble\">Alpha-Numeric Scramble</option><option value=\"Packed-Decimal Scramble\">Packed-Decimal Scramble</option><option value=\"Date-Time Scrambler\">Date-Time Scrambler</option></select>";`

Comment: Sir its working. but unfortunately it is closing automatically. By pressing addRow(). After adding the Row it is closing the window.

Comment: <button runat="server" id="Addnewrow" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add New Row </button>                                      This is C# code                                                                                                            protected void Addnewrow_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownConfigFile.SelectedValue == "Create New")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Edit", "openEditModal();", true); }
 This is the change I made and its working fine now.